# Scancode is missing for XF86 key, yet keycode is available

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland, thinkpad

I have a recent X1 thinkpad w/Fedora OS, and the new F9-F11 special keys don't work. They don't appear to be specified in the XF86 multimedia keys list: notifications, start call, and end call. From archwiki:

> Most of your keys should already have a keycode, or at least a scancode. Keys without a scancode are not recognized by the kernel; these can include additional keys from "gaming" keyboards, etc.

Using `showkeys --scancodes` in terminal, this is confirmed as I get no response to the key presses. Ok, so Fedora kernel doesn't recognize these keyboards inputs. However, `showkeys` gives me keycodes 444-446. How is this possible? Does it mean some signal is being mapped. Not sure how that is possible without at least a scancode input. Does this also mean a scancode can still be mapped to the keycodes in wayland bindings?